# How to modify the $_post data in php?

Tags: php, html

I am new to php programming language.So basically I am creating a simple form.

```html
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Phone No: <input type="text" name="phon" /><br/>
Course:<input type="text" name="course" /> <br />
Experience: <select name="exp"> <option value="beginner">Beginner</option> <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option> <option value="advanced">Advanced</option> </select><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

So the output will be something like this:

```
Array ( [mail] => john [phon] => 123455666 [course] => bsc [exp] => beginner [Submit] => Sign Up )
```

I want to modify or change the output something like this,

`Name=john
Phone No=123455666
Course=bsc
Experience=beginner`

And I want to store that in the arrays, i.e. right hand side parameters in one array and left hand side parameters in another array. So that it will be easy to access or search the data. In the next level of this i want to save these values in a file.

Please help me out.

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $array1= array();
    $array2= array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $key ."=". $value ;
    echo "<br>";
    $array1[]=$key; //first array for left hand side 
    $array2[]=$value; //second array for right hand side

    }
     print_r($array1);  print_r($array2);

     Output:-
    phon=123456
    course=maths
    exp=intermediate
    Submit=Sign Up
Array ( [0] => mail [1] => phon [2] => course [3] => exp [4] => Submit ) Array ( [0] => tet [1] => test [2] => stedt [3] => intermediate [4] => Sign Up )
```

Comment: y the last line is coming i.e. Array ( [0] => mail [1] => phon [2] => course [3] => exp [4] => Submit ) Array ( [0] => tet [1] => test [2] => stedt [3] => intermediate [4] => Sign Up ) what does tat mean??

Comment: it is array output   print_r($array1);  print_r($array2);

Comment: yeah thanku...can u please guide me further..??please

Answer (score 0):

Name of fields are key to $_POST array

```
$_POST['name_of_input']
```

Example:

```
$_POST['mail']
$_POST['phone']
```

Look at `array_keys()` and `array_values()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Take lessons on **MySQL** to store data in database

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set the names you want in the form on the first place.

Changing the $_POST is not a good practice. All it can do is confuse you and anyone else might read your code.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
Phone No: <input type="text" name="Phone No" /><br/>
Course:<input type="text" name="Course" /> <br />
Experience: <select name="Experience"> <option value="beginner">Beginner</option> <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option> <option value="advanced">Advanced</option> </select><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
 #TO DO your operation        
}
```

Comment: This would be much better with a bit of explanation as to what's going on.

Comment: lol,what is not clear.You have here $key  and $value ,and now you can work with them .
I think the problem lies in extracting key from array

Answer (score -1):

Right Hand Side parameters:

```
$rhs_params = $_POST;
```

Left Hand Side parameters:

```
$lhs_params = array_keys($_POST);
```

I am not sure what you are planning to do with this tho!!